# Adding custom tag in html using Xcode

Tags: ipad, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I am in the development phase of an iPad application in which user can edit the html content by using content editable  feature  of uiwebview.  My doubt is that , is there  any control or third party frame work  available for adding a custom tag in the html through uiwebview.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the DOM in the HTML page within the UIWebView and add whatever content you want to the dom.
There is no API or framework available for this.

You have to do it using javascript and execute the javascript using

```
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
```